# How to add horizontal scroll bar to iframe

Tags: css, iframe, horizontal-scrolling

I have this iframe

```
<iframe src="https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/OpenDSA/Books/Everything/html/Write.html#recurWriteStepsCON" scrolling="no" id='frameid1' width=100% height=330px></iframe>
```

In smaller screen devices the iframe is getting cut off. So I want to add a horizontal scroll bar, but not a vertical one. How do I do it? Adding scrolling="no" removes both scroll bars.

Comment: overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden; ?

Comment: I am getting the vertical scroll too !!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve it by hiding the overflow and adding the overflow-x:

```
<iframe style="overflow: hidden; overflow-x: scroll;" src="https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/OpenDSA/Books/Everything/html/Write.html#recurWriteStepsCON" id='frameid1' width=100% height=330px></iframe>
```

Comment: I am getting the vertical scroll too !!